# Prevent Jekyll from processing string

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll collection with frontmatter that includes:

```
image: https://placeimg.com/600/340/nature/1
```

When I try to inline that image url in a page like this:

```
<div style=background-image:url({{ img }})></div>
```

The content gets rendered like this:

```
<div class="product-banner" style="background-image:url(" https:="" placeimg.="" com="" 600="" 340="" nature="" 1)=""></div>
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing, or how I can get Jekyll to process this image properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the quotes around the attribute value, e.g.:

```
<div style='background-image:url({{ img }})'></div>
```

Mama mia.